# Bokeh - How to properly set & control xaxis for datetime - possible bug?

Tags: date, datetime, pandas, axis, bokeh

I am trying to make a basic line & point plot in Bokeh (0.12.3) using the following code. I have set the x_axis_type as 'datetime' and I am plotting a (random) variable vs. a pandas (0.19.0) datetime64 dtype that is the index of the dataframe (i.e. a timeseries).

The problem I see with the plot is that the dates are not properly aligned.  In the time series,  the max date is 2016-11-06,  however,  the last scale tick is for Nov 16,  and there is a point aligned to what appears to be several days after that.

Curiously,  when zooming in the plot,  the alignment looks correct!

Is this a bug,  or am I doing something wrong for this plot?  Do I need to be more specific in how the x-axis should be rendered?

Also, I really think the scale increments should be in equal number of days.  However in this case,  Bokeh plots the scale increments to be on the same day of esch month (which is a varying number of days increments).  I have seen this before in other plots,  and that default can hamper interpretation.

Appreciate any help on this.  Here is the code and the screen shots that demonstrate the issue:

```
# imports & config
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook

output_notebook()

# create a times series dataframe
rng = pd.date_range('2016-07-24', periods=16, freq='W')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index = rng, columns=['Y'])

# view the tail of the data to compare to plot
df.tail()

# make and render the plot
p1 = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',
        title='Y vs Week Ending',
       plot_width=700, plot_height=400)

p1.xaxis.axis_label = 'Week Ending'
p1.yaxis.axis_label = 'Y'
p1.line(df.index, df['Y'])
p1.circle(df.index, df['Y'])
p1.yaxis.minor_tick_line_alpha=0

show(p1)
```

[image: Pre Zoom]

[image: Post Zoom]

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug with that particular scale. Pleas file a report on GitHub with this information. In any event if you don't want the standard datetime ticker behaviour, there is a fixed ticker: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-locations or you can also make a custom extension to implement any ticking policy you like

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and tip.   Will look into the fixed ticker approach!    I added the issue to bokeh github as issue #5436 with the same info and reference to this post.

Answer (score 2):

> the last scale tick is for Nov 16, and there is a point aligned to what appears to be several days after that.

That tick is for Nov **20**16.. it's not very intuitive, but the year is contracted into the label.

Knowing this may change your perspective w.r.t. this comment:

> ...I really think the scale increments should be in equal number of days. However in this case, Bokeh plots the scale increments to be on the same day of [each] month...

What it's done is change the base unit from *day* to *month*, which is probably the more correct approach.

Comment: Wow - did not catch that.  Well,  that explains my misinterpretation of plot.  However,  I will say that most plotting platforms that plot data as a "month" do so treating month as an ordinal (not numeric).  i.e.

Comment: .. month level aggregate data - in which case the tick distance between Jan, Feb and March would all be the same,  even though Jan has 31 days,  Feb has 28 days..